# How can I get a subfield of dictionary in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I've the data structured as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61e810b946788906359966"),
    "titles" : {
        "full_name" : "full name",
        "name" : "name"
    },
    "duration" : 161,
    "work_ids" : {
        "plasma_id" : "METRO_3423659",
        "product_code" : "34324000",
      
    }
}
```

I would like query result as:

```
{'full_name': 'full name', 'plasma_id': 'METRO_3423659'}
```

The query that i do is:

```
 .find({query},{"_id": 0, "work_ids.plasma_id": 1, "titles.full_name": 1}})
```

but the result i get is `'titles': {'full_name': 'full name'}, 'work_ids': {'plasma_id': 'METRO_3423659'}}`

There is any way to get directly the result i want?  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- you can do it using paths, and adding names for the fields

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63245ca878a49d87828514b8)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": 
   {"_id": 0,
    "full_name": "$titles.full_name",
    "plasma_id": "$work_ids.plasma_id"}}])
```